# External monitor resolution not saved

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, display, display-resolution

I have an external screen which I would like set to 1920x1080.

However, everytime I attach the screen, it sets the resolution to 3840x2160.  The screen is not capable of displaying that.  I believe it does this because there is a A/V receiver in between which is likely is communicating what it is capable of passing through, but the end display can't do that high of a resolution.

So I try to manually set it to **1920x1080** in the `Display Settings` control panel interface.  After doing that (twice for some reason), I expect that setting to be saved for this display.  But it keeps reverting to the high resolution each time.

How do I fix this?

Kubuntu 20.04
Nvidia GTX 1660

External display is attached through a passive Display Port to HDMI adapter.  DP on my card are "dual", so an active adapter is not necessary.  Also, the display config screen properly detects my A/V receiver, so it seems to know what device it is talking to - I just want it to save my preferences so I don't have to set it every time I plug the external screen in.

[image]